# ASP.NET Core 5 with Identity - can’t access views decorated with [Authorize]

Tags: angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I’ve spent hours trying to figure out why I can’t access a view after login is successful.  From the Chrome tools I can see a 200 response, token being generated. Then it should navigate to the home page if successful, which it tries, but then I get a 401 (Unauthorized). If I remove the `[Authorize]` decorator or add an `[AllowAnonymous]` it works but that is not what I am looking for. From swagger I see the same behavior. Token persists even after the 401 error. Please help!

**appsettings.json** (hidding key and issuer)

```
  "JWTSettings": {
    "securityKey": "*********",
    "validIssuer": "*********",
    "validAudience": "https://localhost:44393",
    "expiryInMinutes": 5
  }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
    services.AddDbContext<JonathanKrownContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("JonathanKrownArtDb")));

    services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(opt =>
    {
        opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<JonathanKrownContext>();

    var jwtSettings = Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings");
    services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
    {
        opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = jwtSettings["validIssuer"],
            ValidAudience = jwtSettings["validAudience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8
                .GetBytes(jwtSettings.GetSection("securityKey").Value))
        };
    });

    services.AddScoped<JwtHandler>();
```

**JwtHandler.cs**

```
public class JwtHandler
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    private readonly IConfigurationSection jwtSettings;
    public JwtHandler(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        jwtSettings = this.configuration.GetSection("JwtSettings");
    }
    public SigningCredentials GetSigningCredentials()
    {
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings.GetSection("securityKey").Value);
        var secret = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);
        return new SigningCredentials(secret, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    }
    public List<Claim> GetClaims(IdentityUser user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email)
    };
        return claims;
    }
    public JwtSecurityToken GenerateTokenOptions(SigningCredentials signingCredentials, List<Claim> claims)
    {
        var tokenOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: jwtSettings["validIssuer"],
            audience: jwtSettings["validAudience"],
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(jwtSettings["expiryInMinutes"])),
            signingCredentials: signingCredentials);
        return tokenOptions;
    }
}
```

**AccountsController.cs**

```
   [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AccountsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<DataModels.User> userManager;
        private readonly IMapper mapper;
        private readonly JwtHandler jwtHandler;

        public AccountsController(UserManager<DataModels.User> userManager, IMapper mapper, JwtHandler jwtHandler)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.mapper = mapper;
            this.jwtHandler = jwtHandler;
        }
        [HttpPost("Registration")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterUser([FromBody] DomainModels.User userForRegistration)
        {
            if(userForRegistration == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var user = mapper.Map<DataModels.User>(userForRegistration);

            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, userForRegistration.Password);
            if(!result.Succeeded)
            {
                var errors = result.Errors.Select(e => e.Description);

                return BadRequest(new DomainModels.RegistrationResponse { Errors = errors });
            }

            return StatusCode(201);
        }

        [HttpPost("Login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserForAuthentication userForAuthentication)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userForAuthentication.Email);

            if(user == null || !await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, userForAuthentication.Password))
            {
                return Unauthorized(new AuthResponse { ErrorMessage = "Invalid Authentication" });
            }

            var signinCredentials = jwtHandler.GetSigningCredentials();
            var claims = jwtHandler.GetClaims(user);
            var tokenOptions = jwtHandler.GenerateTokenOptions(signinCredentials, claims);
            var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenOptions);

            return Ok(new AuthResponse { IsAuthSuccessful = true, Token = token });
        }
    }
```

**PaintingsController.cs**

```
[Route("[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    public class PaintingsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IPaintingRepository repository;
        private readonly IMapper mapper;
        private readonly ILogger<PaintingsController> logger;
        private readonly IImageRepository imageRepository;

        public PaintingsController(IPaintingRepository repository, IMapper mapper, ILogger<PaintingsController> logger, IImageRepository imageRepository)
        {
            this.repository = repository;
            this.mapper = mapper;
            this.logger = logger;
            this.imageRepository = imageRepository;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(200)]
        [ProducesResponseType(400)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllPaintingsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var claims = User.Claims;
                var paintings = await repository.GetHomePagePaintingsAsync();
                var paintingsDto = mapper.Map<List<Painting>>(paintings);

                return Ok(paintingsDto);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError($"Failed to get paintings: {ex}");
                return BadRequest("Failed to get paintings");
            }
        }
}
```

[image: Token persists even after the 401 error]

[image: 401 error]

Comment: How is that endpoint accessed? The token is in local storage, but how is it used from there?

Comment: @sami THANK YOU SO MUCH for adding this comment. I had been coding for 8 hours straight and was focusing on the API. I was NOT passing the headers on the front-end get request. UGH!